# Install of casperJs on mac and how to link it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, casperjs

I want to install `NodeJs` and `CasperJs` on my MAC system .

I already install `PhantomJs` .

**NodeJs** is working correctly but when I am trying to run **CasperJs** but it gives

error `command not found`

and i am trying to install again using

`MacBook-Pro:/ manish$ brew install casperjs`

then it gives

```
Warning: casperjs-1.0.4 already installed, it's just not linked
```

now any body can tell how to link casperJS

Comment: `brew link casperjs`

Comment: @robertklep thank you